# socket.io emit to specific user and give them x amount of time to respond

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an online chat. It uses rooms. If a user sends message and the other user is not online, it should increment the "missed messages" counter. I tried to create a timeout with `setTimeout` and if they emit an event it clears that timeout.

However `chatOnline` doesn't fire as I expected to, which leads to it always reporting the user is offline and incrementing the counter for `missed_texts` column in `rethinkdb` (which is not shown because it isn't relevant).

How can I retrieve if the user is online from socket.io? My goal is to avoid having to store presence info in the database, which could get out of control quickly.

Code I tried:

```
socket.on('chatSend',function(data){
    if(socket.client.user.room_id !== null){

        //were storing some crap in the socket object for easy retrieval. 
        data.user_id = socket.client.user.id;
        data.room_id = socket.client.user.room_id;
        data.timestamp = ~~(new Date() / 1000);

        //insert message into chat table
        r.table('chat').insert(data).run().then(function(res){


            //retrive generated record from table
            r.table('chat').get(res.generated_keys[0]).run().then(function(data2){


                io.sockets.in(data2.room_id).emit('chatNew',data);//emit to all users in room

                log('chatSend');

                //attempt to see if the other user is online
                getOtherUser(data2.room_id,socket.client.user.id,function(tid){

                    log('other user id: %d',tid);

                    //all users automatically join a room matching their user id when connecting.
                    //unsure how to see if the user is online. this doesnt work.
                    //this is what i need help with. retrieving the other users socket resource if they are online,
                    //and if they are not then return null or false, etc so i can work with that.
                    var othersocket = io.sockets.in(tid);


                    //if timeout completes before they respond, they are not online. 
                    var tmptime = setTimeout(function(){
                        log('other user not online.');
                        othersocket.removeListener('chatOnline',tmpfunc);
                        missedTexts(data2.room_id,tid,'INCR');
                    },5000);

                    var tmpfunc = function(){
                        clearTimeout(tmptime);
                        //remove the listener
                        othersocket.removeListener('chatOnline',tmpfunc);
                    };

                    //emit chatOnline to other user socket
                    //when they respond, cleartimeout, resulting in counter not being incremented.
                    othersocket.on('chatOnline',tmpfunc);
                    othersocket.emit('chatOnline');


                });

            });
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: @bolav its stored in rethinkdb which you can see right in the code... that has nothing to do with the question at all.

Comment: @bolav i updated the question with current state of the code and comments to help you understand it better. my issue is im unable to detect if the other user is in the room.

Comment: I dont think you are going at it from correct angle. You should create separate object for each group in which you store reference to each socket together with indicator if they are active or not. There is a little hint that you might have something like that eg `getOtherUser` but since we cannot see that function, hard to help.

Comment: Why do you have the line `othersocket.emit('chatOnline')`? Was that just for testing? Because that will always cause the timeout to be cleared before it gets a chance to run.

Comment: @Tom there is a `room` record in rethinkdb that indicates the two user who are authorized to access the room. this is completely seperate of socket io but necessary for the logic of the app. i need to detect presence of the other user, and if they are not online increment the number of missed texts for that user. all this logic is in place, i just can't detect if the other user is online. by default, each user joins a room identical to their `user_id` on `connect`. so my idea was to use `io.sockets.in(user_id)`, but it doesn't give me a indication if is anyone in that room or not. any ideas?

Comment: @bolav second time you've posted an irrelevant comment. messages are stored in the db regardless. the problem is i want to know if a user has any unseen messages, so i can show the number of missed messages for each contact on the message inbox screen. so obviously i need to detect if they are not online and increment the counter for that room. understand now?

Comment: @MattBrowne no it doesn't. socket io events are directional aware. you can emit the same event on either side and it fires event on the listening party. so i can emit `chatOnline` from server and it fires in browser, then emit it in browser and it will fire on server.

Comment: @MattBrowne in code above `chatOnline` is never emitted from server because `io.sockets.in(tid)` fails, even if user is online. so the timeout is never cleared, resulting in the counter always being incremented. so as it stands my issue is detecting if the `tid` room exists. remember, `tid` is the user's id and on connect that user joins that room after authentication.

Comment: Your mileage may vary based on what socket.io version you're running, but perhaps I can help guide you? `io.of('/').connected` contains a list of all current connections.  Step through that list, and each connection has a `rooms` array.  Check the rooms array for `.indexOf(tid) >= 0` and if true, the other user is online and you can stop searching. If you complete the loop without a true, the user is off-line (or not in the room with their user id for some reason).

Comment: thanks styletron. i'll give it a try and see what happens. if it works, i'll request you provide this as an official answer.

Comment: 1 thing styletron, not only does the user need to be online, they need to also be in the same room as the other user.

Comment: ultimately it did not work @styletron